# save views->execute result as a static variable

Tags: 7

Does it make sense (performancewise) to store view->execute() as a static variable in order to avoid running same view multiple times?

And then call view->render() wherewer I want to print the view? Does it make any sense? Or are there better options? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on what you're trying to achieve with caching.

If you're trying to avoid additional DB queries, you won't be adding much here. The [`view::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aexecute/7.x-3.x) & [`view::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Arender/7.x-3.x) are already making use of its own caching system (if it's enabled on the view in question).

If you're trying to avoid all the theme/module hook execution overhead, yeah that will avoid it. Of course, the trade-off is modules/themes won't be able to modify a view (if that's needed) and you'll have to handle other cache invalidation scenarios as a result of your custom caching.

You'll have to make the call depending on how/what you're trying to optimize it that's worth the trade-off (generally, I would say no but that's opinion).